# Load partial view with ajax actionlink

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views, actionlink

I've been trying to load a partial view but when clicking the link it inserts the whole site instead of just the partial view. What am I doing wrong?

In my template I have:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("View list",
    "List",
    "SwitchView",
    new AjaxOptions()
         {
        UpdateTargetId = "testajax",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        HttpMethod = "GET"
    })

<div id="testajax"></div>

@section Scripts {
   <script src="@Url.Content("~/Assets/framework/js/unobtrusive-ajax/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
}
```

My controller:

```
public class SwitchViewController : Controller
    {
        public PartialViewResult List()
        {
            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/kund.unikum.se/_ListView");
        }
    }
```

I've also added these settings in web.config since they were missing:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Also, when looking at the generated html link it's missing a "href" value?

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#testajax" href="">View list</a>
```

[Screenshot of the loaded resources and the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mepbr.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `Layout=null` in the partial view? if not then set and check. let me know if you still facing the issue.

Comment: Yup, the partial view only exists of this:

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>Hello</h1>

Comment: The console is throwing "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated..."?

Comment: Is it possible that the ajax target element lives inside of @RenderBody could cause issues?

Comment: NO, I will try to recreate a demo and let you know soon.

Comment: Hello @David, can you please share more details because it's working fine here.
can you please check that your jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js loaded in the do ?

Comment: Main view Content 

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1IGBb4gwWiKmOr49zzJBR3ACPJlCOk4rn

Comment: Controller content 
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1Vv9ew8G2aMcYhedeXO8QFWAzfUnet8Od

Comment: Patial View

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1joXFoKq28jn9A-Z3FQoVqKUX56N3iYc5

Comment: See result on below Link

https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1eF7eegZBHWD-tvavsaUKX9qcK8T9bN1Y

Comment: This is super wierd. From what I can see our code looks identical but I'm not able to load the partial view. Still a duplicate of the site appears where the partial view is suppose to load. 

I've checked and to me it looks like the unobtrusive js is loaded as it should. Would it matter if I have the script below the markup? I have the jqurey library and the unobtrusive js loaded after all of the content.

I've updated the post with a screenshot of the js resources loaded and the result of the page.

Comment: If you check your html output, does your actionlink have a href value?

Comment: From what I can see I'm running MVC 5.2.3 and using jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min for MVC 3.0. But this is the latest unobtrusive-ajax version so I guess this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: <a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="GET" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-update="#testajax" href="/Home/List">View list</a>

@version v3.2.6
unobtrusive.ajax file loaded before the link rendered
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1xlLUsFL_X-QAAshtmyRpajDCT8sOwwq_

Comment: Okey, so you load the unobtrusive.ajax file before the link is rendered, in that case you are also loading the jqurey library before the link is rendered. I always tend to load the jqurey library at the bottom of my content. I will try this, loading jqurey library in the head, the unobtrusive.ajax file before the link is rendered and see what happens...

Comment: This is just for an example I have placed link on my existing page. where others function is there, but still, you check

Comment: I've added the jqurey library and the unobtrusive.ajax (3.2.6) file in the head in that order. In other words before the link is rendered. The js looks like they are loaded correctly. Still it's not working... What jqurey version are you using?

Comment: Hello, @David I have jquery version jquery-1.10.2.min.js, also a script rendered in the head section in the layout view.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it working... I inherited the wrong controller... Gaaah. Thanks for your help!